# Differences between encrypting an actual PC vs a virtual one?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, truecrypt, disk-encryption, esxi

Are there any differences between using for example TrueCrypt to encrypt the system drive of an actual PC and a virtual one running on ESXi?

Are there any security advantages/differences?

Comment: Why would there be?